# Nodeclipse plugin for NodeJS development in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, nodeclipse

Upon searching on the internet, I found out that nodeclipse  plugin for NodeJS development in Eclipse. I have tried to install it but I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/.
http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ is not a valid repository location.
```

http://nodeclipse.org/ is also not available.

I have tried Enide also but it is also showing the same error.

Can anyone tell me a good platform for NodeJS development or how to install nodeclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like http://nodeclipse.org/ isn't reachable, but http://www.nodeclipse.org/ is.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Nevermind.  I guess I need a lesson in reading comprehension today.  It looks like you did try that.

Answer (score 0):

Nodeclipse site was [unavailable for few days](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/207).

Anyone can download offline packages from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nodeclipse/files/
or raise an issue at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/